# Working between Activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Okay I am really new to android development and looked around for a clear explanation but couldn't find much. I'll try to be as clear as possible in my question.

Basically, lets say I have 2 Activities, a Create Activity which contains a form with text boxes, etc. (information the user fills out), and a create button on the bottom. My second activity called Creations is basically empty visually until a user creates something with the form in the Create Activity.

So I have a method for when the create button is clicked in the Create Activity

```
 public void create(View view){

    Creations.make(info1, blah1, blah2, etc);

}
```

Now this make() method is in the Creations Activity, it draws a custom view on that page with the info submitted and I want it to be called every time the user clicks the create button in the Create Activity. I know I cannot do this unless make() is a static method, but then how else would I implement this? I know I would have to make an object of my Creations Activity but then wont I have to make multiple objects of the same activity for every new item I want to add?

Comment: You say you are new to Android. Do you understand that an `Activity` is basically a UI framework and is only considered to be in a running state when fully visible? If so, when and how will the Creations `Activity` be started?

Comment: You should read more on developer.android.com and complete the tutorials.  You are way off track.  You should not add static methods to Activities and should be passing values to new activities with `Intent`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough the Creations Activity is started when the user accesses it through a button. So its like this                                                                                (Creations <- Main page -> Create Form)  so you can always access the creations activity from the main page or you can add to it through the create form activitiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you do not need to create an explicit `object` of an activity, you just need to start an activity with the api `startActivity()`;

now, in your case,

there will be a method `onCreatePressed()` in `CreateActivity` as shown below,

```
public void onCreatePressed(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, CreationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_INFO, info);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_BLAH1, blah1);
    .
    .

    CreateActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in `CreationActivity` you will have to override `onCreate()` method, which would look like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    /* if info type is of int there is a method getIntExtra and so on, 
     * if it is a custom class then it must implement Serializable interface 
     * and there is method getSerializableExtra for this.
     */ 
    InfoType info = intent.get<InfoType>Extra(KEY_INFO);
    .
    .
    .

    // setContentView(some_resource_id);

    // inflate it with the data. 
}
```

Comment: Okay I see what your doing so your using Intent to send data to the CreationActivity. But now say I go back to the Create form and submit another set of data, I want that new data to be added in the CreationActivity without overriding the previous data, so I'm basically adding a new set of data, would using this method work?

Comment: for that purpose while going back you will have to store `old` data to somewhere like. file, shared preferences or in db, so that you can show `old` as well as `new` data in CreationActivity.

I will suggest you to go thr' this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development/dp/0470565527)